# Will pushf and popf cause VMEXIT in virtual machine on x86 platform?

Tags: linux, x86, virtual-machine, virtualization, instructions

I am trying to add some codes in linux kernel running in virtual machine powered by kvm. However, I find the instruction `pushf` and `popf` will cause dramatic performance overhead, with at most 5x slowdown for apache. I am sure it is these 2 instructions that cause the overhead because if I replace them with `lahf` and `sahf`, the overhead is gone.

Now I wonder why they bring so much degradation and how to avoid them? I find some clues in [this slide](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/b4m36esw/esw12_2017.pdf), which indicates that pushf and popf will be trapped into hypervisor. Do they really cause VMEXIT and what is the `exit_reason` number? Finally, is there anyway to configure VMCS so that `pushf` and `popf` will not be trapped?

Comment: It doesn't seem that `pushf` and `popf` cause a VMEXIT, nor it seems the slide is suggesting so.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I am not sure either, but `pushf` and `popf` does cause severe performance overhead compared with `lahf` and `sahf`. I don't know if these extra bits of EFLAGS could make such a obvious difference, and the only reasonable thing I could think of is VMEXIT.

Comment: @MargaretBloom If I get some time recently, I will try to add some counter in kvm and see if it indeed increases., but that is uncertain. Do you have any suggestions about the reason?

Comment: Hum, not really I'm afraid. The VMX extensions are becoming huge and I've never read them completely. There are a few users here that work with virtualization professionally, I hope they'll stop by :)

Answer (score 3):

On Intel processors, all instructions that can cause a VM exit or that have different behavior in a guest are described in volume 3, chapter 25 of the SDM. Pushf and popf are not listed anywhere in that chapter, which means that those instructions do not cause a VM exit, and their observable behavior when executed in a guest is the same as when executed outside a guest.

The reason no VM exit is required for the popf instruction (notwithstanding the slides referenced in the question) is that the VMCS has controls to override behaviors that are normally controlled by the flags register. For example, while in the guest, the IF flag doesn't solely control delivery of interrupts; instead, flags in the VMCS control whether external interrupts are delivered to the guest or whether a VM exit occurs.

It doesn't surprise me that popf has a non-trivial performance impact, considering all that it does. See the description of popf in the software developer's manual for details.

Comment: 5x slowdown does seem excessively high. I can't explain that.

Comment: According to [Agner Fog's uarch guide / instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize), on Skylake `popf` is 9 uops with one per 20 cycle throughput.  I think that's in user mode (ring 3) on non-virtualized hardware; I don't know if different microcode would run in ring 0.  But anyway, the OP is talking about apache, so we can assume ring 3 unless they're tuning a kernel that apache runs on.  (LAHF/SAHF are 1 uop each, with 1c latency.)

Comment: But yeah 5x *total* slowdown doesn't make sense to me either, unless it did cause a VM exit.  20 cycles is a lot less than one cache miss, or something like 1.5x branch mispredicts.  It shouldn't be catastrophic unless apache is spending all its time in a hot loop running this.  But anyway, whatever your micro-optimization problem is, pushf/popf are probably *not* part of an optimal solution to it.  `lahf` and/or `seto`  are more likely to be useful, or just let the CPU handle partial-flag merges in an adc loop using dec/jnz.  Only P6-family had bad partial-flag stalls, not SnB.

Comment: @prl Thanks, it seems the overhead is inside the instruction itself. I shall see the intel manual for details.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the link. I am not trying to tune the kernel for apache, but implementing a simplified [nested kernel](http://nathandautenhahn.com/downloads/publications/asplos200-dautenhahn.pdf) to measure its potential overhead. Currently only modifications to cr0, cr3, cr4 and page table are replaced with its gate. I think the overhead not only affects apache. Actually the `fork` and `exec` call has more than 8x slowdown, which is unreasonably scary for me. `lahf` and `seto` seems much more efficient, but it ignores the IF bit.

Comment: @biggerfish: `pushf` is only 3 uops; you could consider optimistically checking to see if IF matches, using a branch to skip `popf`.  Like maybe `pushf` / `mov eax, [rsp]` / some check on the saved IF vs. the current IF, and then run either OF-restore + sahf + pop rax (to clear the pushf result), *or* `mov [rsp], rdx` / `popf`.  Or maybe you can guarantee that your code only runs while interrupts are enabled so you don't need to save/restore IF?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think among all the placed I have replaced so far, interrupt is enabled. But IF bit seems not the reason of overhead because I will manually `cli` to disable the interrupt anyway. It seems there is no better way than manually measuring the cost of `pushf` and `popf` to confirm the latency?

Comment: @biggerfish: Agner Fog doesn't list a latency for `pushf` or `popf`, only throughputs. (1/c and 1/20c respectively on SKL, which is the slowest.)  But I don't see your point about `cli`. `popf` potentially has to change the machine state in ways that affect the rest of the pipeline, whatever the previous value of IF. If you're using `popf` right before `cli`, maybe clear that bit with AND before popping so you don't need to CLI. Anyway, if you're seeing massive slowdowns, are you sure one of the versions of your code doesn't have a bug that leaves interrupts disabled for too long or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes The sequence is like `pushf; cli;`, and when leaving, the sequence is like `sti; popf;`. I remember I have tried to eliminate `cli` and `sti` completely and the result is the same, but I will try to confirm it.

Comment: Ok, then you could just `popf` instead of `sti`/`popf`, because you saved RFLAGS *before* disabling interrupts.  Then you don't accidentally re-enable interrupts if this code ran when interrupts were supposed to be disabled.  You don't even need an `or qword [rsp], 1<<IF_position` unless you're sure you want to unconditionally enable interrupts, and they might have been be disabled before `cli`.  If you don't need to disable interrupts, though, don't use `cli` either.